# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: curl, https, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install Docker Compose on my Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine but I get the following error:

```
(1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

The command I want to run to install Docker Compose:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

If I run `curl --version` I get:

```
curl 7.67.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.67.0
Release-Date: 2019-11-06
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have something wrong in your curl tool. However I think that you can try with `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`. Did you try to run the curl command without the secure protocol? eg.:

```
sudo curl -L "http://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it with http right now and it says "curl: (1) Unsupported protocol".

Comment: can you try with wget command?
`wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)`

This will download the binary file. Then you should set the execution flag to the file and execute it